# Tkinter not updating cursor

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor, windows-10

I'm trying to update my cursor while my program is busy.

This snippet works:

```
import tkinter as tk
def button():
    root.configure(cursor="watch")
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x500")
button_1 = tk.Button(master=root,command=button,width=10)
button_1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

When I click the button the cursor changes

But this snippet fails:

```
import tkinter as tk
def button():
    root.configure(cursor="watch")
    input("Force a pause")
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x500")
button_1 = tk.Button(master=root,command=button,width=10)
button_1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

It only updates the cursor if I make another window active (or after entering some dummy input)

I've tried adding

```
root.configure(cursor="watch")
root.update()
```

but it still doesn't work (and anyway the tk man says it's a bad idea to put an update() in a callback)

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code update the cursor but it's only done after your busy process is terminated.
So you can execute your busy process in a thread to prevent the user interface to freeze.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def worker():
    for x in range(0, 100000):
        print(x)
    root.config(cursor="arrow")

def button():
    root.config(cursor="watch")
    threading.Thread(target=worker).start() 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x500")
root.config(cursor="arrow")

button_1 = tk.Button(master=root, command=button, width=10)
button_1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks